# PHP Base64 string image upload not working with Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient; using GOOGLE STORAGE BUCKET

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, file-upload, base64, codeigniter-3

I need to upload image from mobile APP so we have API that take base64 string image and upload it to server. It's working fine on our current server but now we are migrating to Google Cloud so it's not working

When i visit the image from browser it shows error response i need solution in PHP code

I already have placed code for that

```
/* working fine in current server */            
$file = $DIR.$imagename;
$ifp = fopen($file, "wb"); 
$data = explode(',', $base64img);
fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($data[1])); 
fclose($ifp);


/* Now i have changed above current server code for Gcloud as following */
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'projectId' => getenv("PROJECT_ID"),
]);
$bucket = $storage->bucket(getenv("GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET"));

$object = $bucket->upload(file_get_contents(base64_decode($data[1])), [
    'name' => $file,
    'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead',
]);
```

Now when i visits image URL from browser it showing following response and file not uploading on gcloud all permission are already given

URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/mydomain.appspot.com/uploads/users/111111/docs/12241/92ddc8390754da02b4e8d34d6a33680.jpg

Showing following error:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access denied.</Message>
    <Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to mydomain.appspot.com/uploads/users/111111/docs/12241/92ddc8390754da02b4e8d34d6a33680d.jpg.</Details>
</Error>
```

Comment: Running `print_r($object->reload(['projection' => 'full']));`, verify that the object exists and the ACLs are set properly. Can you access the image by clicking the hyperlink in the console?

Comment: Are you trying to upload from your app to Google Cloud Storage? If yes, you will need to use Cloud Storage Signed-URLs. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Comment: Normal file upload using POST working fine i just want to upload file using bas64 image string so just want to know whats wrong in this line only @JohnHanley   $object = $bucket->upload(file_get_contents(base64_decode($data[1])), [

Comment: Your problem is not with that line. Your problem is that your bucket objects does not allow the world to read the URL. You either need to make the object public-read or use signed-URLS.

Comment: This message tells you the problem `Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access`